# Are there any magical objects from any fantasy world which work similarly to the Hold Person spell from D&D?

Tags: magic

I'm looking for any magical weapons or artifacts which have the power to bind the wielder's enemies. It can be literally binding them with conjured chains, or just something like paralyzing them temporarily. Basically, making them unable to move and fight back for a while, like the Hold Person spell does in D&D.

For example: a magical staff which will make a person it's pointed at unable to move when a spell is spoken.

It just needs to be from an existing book series (or a movie, a game, etc.)

Comment: This is waaaaay too broad. Binding spells are a huge trope, as are stunning spells; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SupernormalBindings, http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChainPain, http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicStaff

Comment: And this; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HarmlessFreezing

Comment: Thanks, I'll read through those links now. I'm looking for something to be used against humans, not demons or fairies, and also something that would be usable in a combat situation (e.g. not "magical manacles" which can only be applied after the target is down, anyway). I guess I should have clarified that from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Richard when he claims that it's too broad, but still, you deserve an awnser nonetheless.

It's pretty easy to think about one example, let's take Harry Potter:

Here's the description of the **Full Body-Bind Curse** in the Harry Potter Universe:

> "Neville's arms snapped to his sides. His legs sprang together. His whole body rigid, he swayed where he stood and then fell flat on his face, stiff as a board. Neville's jaws were jammed together so he couldn't speak. Only his eyes were moving, looking at them in horror."

It fits under your description of:

> For example: a magical staff which will make a person it's pointed at unable to move when a spell is spoken.

In this case, a wand

Comment: (aka Petrificus Totalus)